# Rails site and static html site with nginx and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have nginx and passenger set up on an ubuntu14.04 server, the rails site works and can be accessed by the ip address however I've also added a static site to server but it never shows up when I enter the site address it only shows the rails site, I have no idea why this is....
below are my conf files in sites-enabled for each site

my rails site

```
   server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name http://xx.x.x.x.x;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env    production;
            root         /home/deploy/railssite/current/public;

            # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }
    }
```

my static site;

```
server {
        listen   80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.xxxxx.net xxxxx.net;

        root /home/deploy/staticsite/current;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }
        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires 365d;
    }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

can anyone see what is wrong here?
I've restarted the nginx server and still just see the rails site.

The rails site is using the vps' ip address and the static site is using a domain name.

Comment: are both sites enabled? like in the `sites-enabled` folder ?

Comment: The location mentioned for the rails site and static site seems to be the same. modify the "location /" in the static site to " location /some-sub-folder ". See if that fixes it.

Comment: both sites are enabled

Comment: both sites have different roots and therefore different locations